# Creating cte statement to traverse a tree created with a bridge table

Tags: sql, tree, common-table-expression

I will preface this by saying that I am completely new to cte statements.

I have 2 tables an items table and a linker table. the linker table containing the parent id and child id of the relationship.
I have seen lots of examples on how to traverse a tree with what I believe is called an associative system, where the parent id is stored on the child record instead of in a bridge table. But I can not seem to extrapolate this out to my scenario.
I believe I need to have a bridge table like this because any single item could have multiple parents and each parent will most likely have multiple children.

I hacked together my own way of traversing the tree but it was within another language, xojo, and I really did not like how it turned out. Essentially I was using recursive functions to dig down into each tree and queried the database each time I needed a child.

Now I am trying to create a cte statement that does the same thing. Keeping the descendants ordered below the parents is not a huge deal

So I have created a sample database and other materials to describe my issue:

This diagram shows visually what the relationships are:
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQVLr.png)

This is what I would like returned from the database (some items show up in multiple places:

```
    1 : Audio
        2 : Speaker
        3 : Microphone
        4 : Mic Pack
            3 : Microphone
            5 : Di
                6 : Passive Di
                    11 : Rapco Di
                    13 : Dbx Di
    7 : Lighting
        9 : Safety
            12 : Small Safety
    8 : Rigging
        10 : Light Rigging
            9 : Safety
                12 : Small Safety
```

An example table:
    CREATE TABLE `items` ( `id` INTEGER, `name` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`) );

```
CREATE TABLE `linker` ( `parent` INTEGER, `child` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`parent`,`child`) );

Insert Into items(id, name) Values(1, 'Audio');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(2, 'Speaker');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(3, 'Microphone');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(4, 'Mic Pack');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(5, 'Di');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(6, 'Passive Di');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(7, 'Lighting');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(8, 'Rigging');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(9, 'Safety');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(10, 'Lighting Rigging');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(11, 'Rapco Di');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(12, 'Small Safety');
Insert Into items(id, name) Values(13, 'Dbx Di');

Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(1, 2);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(1, 4);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(1, 3);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(4, 3);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(4, 5);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(5, 6);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(6, 11);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(6, 13);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(7, 9);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(9, 12);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(8, 10);
Insert Into linker(parent, child) Values(10, 9);
```

This is the cte that I came up with that I believe came the closest, but its probably still pretty far off:

```
  with cte As
    (
    Select 
        id,
   name,
   0 as level,
   Cast(name as varchar(255) as sort
    From items i
    Left outer Join
    linker li
    On i.id = li.child
    And li.parent is Null

    Union All

    Select 
        id,
        name,
        cte.level + 1,

        Cast(cte.sort + '.' + i.name As Varchar(255)) as sort
    From cte
    Left Outer Join linker li
    on li.child = cte.id
    Inner Join items i
    On li.parent = i.id
    )

Select 
    id,
    name,
    level,

    sort
From cte
Order By Sort;
```

Thanks for any help in advance. I am very open to the idea that everything I am doing from the data structure up is wrong, so keep that in mind when you are answering.

Edit: It is probably worth noting that the results don't need to be in order. I plan on creating a ancestry path field in the cte statement, and using that patb to populate my tree.

Edit: oops, I copied and pasted the wrong bit of cte code. I am on mobile so I did my best to change it to what I was doing on my desktop. Once I have a chance I will double check the cte statement against my notes.

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: I am planning on using python with sqlalchemy and sqlite. Is that what your asking?

Comment: Could you adapt the CTE you came up with to your sample data? I'm guessing `tbl_event`=`items` and `tbl_events_events`=`linker`?

Comment: Sander, yes your assumsions are correct. I edited the statement to what I'm pretty sure I was trying at the end of yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, seems like my brain just needed some rest. I have figured out a solution to my issue with much less frustration than yesterday.

My cte statement was:

```
with cte As(
    Select 
       id,
       name, 
       li.parent,
       li.child,
       Cast(name as Varchar(255)) as ancestory
    From items i
    Left Outer Join linker li
    On i.id = li.child
    Where li.parent is null

    Union All

    Select 
        i.id,
        i.name,
        li.parent,
        li.child,
        Cast(cte.ancestory || "." || i.name as Varchar(100)) as ancestory
    From cte
    Left join linker li
    On cte.id = li.parent
    Inner Join items i
    On li.child = i.id

        )
select * from cte
```

The results come back as:

```
  id    name        parent    child    ancestory
   1    Audio                          Audio
   7    Lighting                       Lighting
   8    Rigging                        Rigging
   2    Speaker       1          2     Audio.Speaker
   3    Microphone    1          3     Audio.Microphone
   4    Mic Pack      1          4     Audio.Mic Pack
   9    Safety        7          9     Lighting.Safety
  10    Lighting      8         10     Rigging.Lighting Rigging
         Rigging
   3    Microphone    4          3     Audio.Mic Pack.Microphone
   5    Di            4          5     Audio.Mic Pack.Di
  12    Small         9         12     Lighting.Safety.Small Safety
         Safety
   9    Safety       10          9     Rigging.Lighting Rigging.Safety
   6    Passive Di    5          6     Audio.Mic Pack.Di.Passive Di
  12    Small Safety  9         12     Rigging.Lighting Rigging.Safety.Small Safety
  11    Rapco Di      6         11     Audio.Mic Pack.Di.Passive Di.Rapco Di
  13    Dbx Di        6         13     Audio.Mic Pack.Di.Passive Di.Dbx Di
```